# How do I switch Ubuntu 22.10 to Wayland and use the NVIDIA PRIME RENDER OFFLOAD with Xwayland?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, wayland

I'm looking for a good tutorial to learn how to switch Ubuntu 22.10 to Wayland and then use the NVIDIA PRIME RENDER OFFLOAD with Xwayland. On the internet there are a lot of sources, but due to the fact that it just didn't work until some time ago, a lot of them are only a wasting of time. So, if someone has been able to do that, can you share the method that worked? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest Ubuntu 22.04, and the Nvidia drivers 520+
(Earlier versions hadn't been made to work)

The Wayland choice is made at login: when the password field is present for login, click on the little gear in the lower right corner and choose the wayland or the non-xorg choice (they vary depending upon your hardware).

When running Wayland, maybe some things like the cuda samples need the following to run:

```
$ __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia ./nbody
```

The xrandr providers get switched sometimes -- not sure under what conditions now, but used to be from the choice of "performance".  The environment variables allow you to select the one you want to be the one used for a program.  Such a choice may be made permanent, in your login scripts if you want.

When the cuda samples fail for wrong gpu, you get an error like

```
CUDA error at bodysystemcuda_impl.h:191 code=999(cudaErrorUnknown) "cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&m_pGRes[i], m_pbo[i], cudaGraphicsMapFlagsNone)"
```

When running the xorg,  xrandr --listproviders will list your providers but under Wayland, it just says 0 providers.